# What team has the shortest "longest losing streak" within a season in MLB history?

Tags: baseball, statistics, history, mlb

Don't know if the wording of the title makes sense, but I want to know what team had the longest losing streak that was the shortest in MLB history (or at least the live ball era)

A completely made up example (LLS -Longest Losing Streak):

> 2016
>   Yankees LLS 5
>   Red Sox LLS 6
>   Braves LLS 8
>   2015
>   Yankees LLS 7
>   Red Sox LLS 4
>   Braves LLS 3.

The Braves would have the shortest longest losing streak

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say the 2001 Seattle Mariners who's shortest longest winning streak was 4, that is the season they won 116 games.

Comment: @New-To-IT I thought so too along with the 1998 Yankees. I used those teams as benchmarks, and was able to find teams with shorter losing streaks thus far.

Comment: The wording certainly makes sense. The "diameter" of a mathematical object can be defined as the *longest* of all the *shortest* paths between all possible pair of points in the object. (That is, find the two points where the shortest path between them is maximal; that's the diameter. On a square, for example, the points are two opposing corners and the diameter is the length of the diagonal.) There are many other similar definitions in mathematics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since 1920, the start of the live-ball era, the shortest losing streak among MLB teams with 100+ wins in one season appears to be 3.

The following teams achieved this (including a couple of teams that didn't get to 100 wins):

- [1928 Yankees](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1928&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=NYY&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1932 Yankees](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1932&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=NYY&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1940 Reds](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1940&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=CIN&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1954 Yankees](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1954&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=NYY&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1970 Orioles](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1970&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=BAL&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1980 Yankees](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1980&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=NYY&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1988 Dodgers](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1988&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=LAD&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks) (98 wins)
- [2003 Braves](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=2003&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=ATL&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [2005 Cardinals](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=2005&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=STL&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [2016 Indians](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=2016&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=CLE&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks) (94 wins)

The following teams have also achieved this, but with a 4-game (or more) non-winning streak (ie, a tie occurred among the losses):

- [1936 Yankees](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1936&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=NYY&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)
- [1968 Tigers](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.cgi?games=4&year=1968&SHOW=TOT&includes=nospan_years&game_start=10&game_end=135&teams=DET&orderby=losses&submit=Find+Streaks)

I used [Baseball Reference's streak analyzer](http://www.baseball-reference.com/games/streaks.shtml) for my findings. In theory, a .500 team can have a losing streak of only 1. Moreover, it is possible that a under 100-win team can have a shorter losing streak than 3. However, with respect to conjecture, these scenarios are unlikely...but will yield to any season that happens to have a shorter losing streak than 3.

Comment: Does anyone understand why the links here have `game_start=10&game_end=135`? That would seem to me to be restricting things to only a bit of the season which seems wrong, but I'm not confident enough to change it.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Baseball reference uses [10 and 135 respectively](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/streaks.cgi) as placeholder text. The links must've included those parameters accidentally during the answerer's research. I would say it's safe to remove.

Answer (score 7):

Going way, way, way, *way* back the record is held by the [Cincinnati Red Stockings of 1869](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cincinnati_Red_Stockings#Perfect_Season) with their undefeated season; exactly how many matches they won depends on which matches you want to count, but they didn't lose any. 1869 obviously isn't the live ball era, but it is the year that MLB recognise as the start of professional baseball.