# What team has shortest "longest losing streak" within a season in NBA history?

Tags: basketball, statistics, history, nba

Inspired by this question: [What team has shortest longest losing streak within a season in MLB history?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13954/what-team-has-shortest-longest-losing-streak-within-a-season-in-mlb-history)

What team has shortest "longest losing streak" within a season in NBA history? Off the top of my head, the 2015-2016 Golden State Warriors and the 1995-1996 Chicago Bulls are the most likely to have achieved short losing streaks given they lost 9 and 10 games throughout their respective seasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2015-2016 Golden State Warriors lasted an entire season without losing back-to-back games on their way of posting an all-time regular season best record of 73-9. Therefore, the shortest longest losing streak among NBA teams in one season is 1.

That very same season, the San Antonio Spurs lasted 78 games before losing back-to-back(-to-back) games. Next on the list was the 1984-1985 Celtics who lasted 74 games before losing back-to-back games.

[Source](http://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/26138437/lowly-suns-beat-nba-best-bucks-again)

In addition, the [1995-1996 Bulls](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/CHI/1996.html) lasted 45 games before losing back-to-back games. Also, the Warriors went [146 games](https://www.cbssports.com/nba/news/with-no-durant-warriors-146-game-streak-without-consecutive-losses-ends-takeaways/) without losing back-to-back games between 2015-2017.