# What is the fewest number of series lost by a baseball team in a season?

Tags: baseball, history, mlb

In baseball, a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(baseball)) is 2 or more consecutive games against the same team.  For a 3-game series, a team loses that series if they lose 2 or all 3 of the games.  For a 4-game series, a team loses that series if they lose 3 or all 4 of the games.

What is the fewest number of series lost by a MLB team during a regular season?

Comment: [Zero](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/13955/6126). I'll post that as answer if you want, but you might instead want to set a timeframe on this.

Comment: Yes I will edit the question.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the MLB season hasn't always been exactly 162 games, so having 1 less series loss in a shorter season isn't necessarily better.